# mysql dropdown loop - how to insert correctly

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm looking for some help with my INSERT mysql query, I currently have the php loop

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT clientID,clientName FROM clients";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  ?><option value="
  <?php echo $data['clientID'] ?>" >
  <?php echo $data['clientName'] ?></option>
  <?php 
} ?>
```

This outputs the list of Clients that I have, but I need to INSERT the chosen client. **How do I insert the clientID chosen in a html form and insert it into 'projects' ?**

`projectID ('projects')` and `clientID ('clients')` are related, so I need to insert to clientID into projects to associate them together.

Example:

```
$strSql="INSERT INTO projects 
   ( projectID , projectName , projectBusiness , projectDescription) VALUES 
   (NULL , '$strprojectName', '$intclientID', '$strProjectDescription')";
```

The above doesn't grab the clientID yet..

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd ask that, i'm looking for help as I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: because it's trivial question, about basics.

Comment: Beneath you is it? Well thanks for being a supportive community member!

Comment: I don't like questions like "do this work for me, I'm too lazy for it".

Comment: Stop wasting time browsing a website designed to ask questions then..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the more fundamental aspects of PHP (and HTML to an extent) and so you should get a good grasp of this before going much further.

Wrap the select in a form. You may, or may not have done this already; can't tell.

```
<form id="add_client_id" name="add_client_id" method="post" action="script.php">
    <select name="client_id">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="1">Foo</option>
        <option value="2">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Once you submit this form, you can access it from the super global [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) (this is because the forms `method` is set to `post`. Again - fundamentals.

You can now access the `value` of the submit data in the form of an associative array:

`$client_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['client_id']);` - where the key comes from the form.

You can now use this variable within your queries and for further processing - after sanitising of course.

Again this is extremely basic; so you should probably do a bit of work looking for basic PHP tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write that, I wasn't aware whether it would insert the value or text, and in a forehead slapping moment realised what was going on.

Comment: @Ross, don't just mention sanitizing, practice it.